# Why does my linux ffmpeg output file require running it back through ffmpeg to play on windows

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using the following to screen capture a Raspberry Pi display:

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -v quiet -f lavfi -i anullsrc -f x11grab -framerate 30 -video_size 720x480 -i :0.0 -f flv -b:v 1M /home/pi/usbdrv/myfile.avi"
```

I stop screen capturing by hitting the letter q and ffmpeg exits without error.

I can play it back with mplayer in Linux.

However, when I try to play it back on Windows with the old media player or its newer movie player, they reports it is corrupted.  I tried mp4 and mkv fromats as well.

If I run it back through ffmpeg to encode it to a new file, it will play.

Any thoughts why Windows will not play it without running it back through ffmpeg again?

Thanks,
Sean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out.

The -f flv option instructs ffmpeg to output to the format flv, but the output filename I specified had a .avi extension which confused Windows.  Removing the -f flv option from the command line fixed it.

Comment: With MP4 output it is recommended to add the `-vf format=yuv420p` output option for it to play in Windows Media Player.